# node.js: closure in loop

Tags: node.js, loops, closures

I cant get a hang on closures. A very simple example:

```
var array = [1,2,3];
var test = [0,0];
var result = [];
for (var i=1; i<=array.length; i++){    
    test[1] = i;
    result.push(test);
}
console.log(result);
```

If I just push "i" into the result, it outputs "1,2,3", but the way above I always get "[0,3],[0,3][0,3]". Why is that? I have read some explanations on closures, but I dont seem to understand the system, which makes it very hard to find additional errors in my code. Isnt there an easier way to resolve the problem above, than using functions inside functions (that seems to be the solution to every equivalent problem I have found so far)?

Comment: The problem is not really a closure problem, it's that you're re-using the exact same instance of test for all 3 entries you push, so when you change one entry they all change. What are you really trying to achieve by declaring test a single time outside the loop?

Comment: Hi Joachim, thx for the insight. Your first sentence already did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

You are writing same instance to result and when you change parameter in that instance, all instances in result are changed. You need to create separate instances to keep data, here is code to illustrate right way to do this

```
var array = [1,2,3];
var test = [0,0];
var result = [];
for (var i=1; i<=array.length; i++){
    var z = [test[0], i];
    result.push(z);
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

The point is when you substitute Array in JavaScript, It's not copying but giving a link to the Array.
So

```
var testArray = [1,2,3];
var copy = testArray;
copy[1] = 10;
console.log(testArray); // [1,10,3]
```

to avoid this, you can "copy" Array by .concat() or .slice()

```
var testArray = [1,2,3];
var copy = testArray.concat(); // or Array.slice(0)
copy[1] = 10;
console.log(testArray) // [1,2,3]
```

so your code would be

```
var array = [1,2,3];
var test = [0,0];
var result = [];
for (var i=1; i<=array.length; i++){    
    test[1] = i;
    result.push(test.concat());
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: You are shadowing the native `Array` identifier with a variable name, please NEVER do that unless you have an extremely good reason.

Comment: Thank you for the help, this is exactly what I needed. I am creating new entries with an existing entry as template but didnt know it was only a link (the way I did it).

Comment: @Benjamin Grunbaum You are right, I didn't run the code, just writing the code directly here.ima fix it. thanks for your comment